# Integration on Complex Plane (Imaginary part)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is wrong solution, but I don't know how to solve it with another way. I need some help to forward me in right way.

$\int z Im(\overline z)dz, L: x=y^2, z_1 = 0, z_2 = 4+2i$

My solution:

$A(0;0), B(4;2)$

$y(x) = \sqrt x$ - parabola

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9rww.jpg)

Because $x_1 < x_2$ I use formula:

$\int_L f(x;y)dl=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x;y(x))*\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx$

Find the derivative and simplify the root:

$y'(x)=(\sqrt x)'=(x^{1 \over 2})' = {1 \over 2 \sqrt x}$

$\sqrt {1+(y'(x))^2} = \sqrt {1+({ 1 \over 2 \sqrt x})^2}= \sqrt {1 + {1 \over 4x}}$

Because $f(x;y)= y$ and $y(x) = \sqrt x$, then $f(x;y(x)) = \sqrt x$

Use the formula:

$\int_L ydl = \int_0^4 \sqrt x * \sqrt {1+{1 \over 4x}} dx = \int_0^4 \sqrt{x* (1+{1 \over 4x})}dx = \int_0^4 \sqrt{x+{1 \over 4}}dx =$

$= {1 \over 2} \int_0^4 (x+{1 \over x})^{1 \over 2} d(x+{1 \over 4}) = {1 \over 2} *{1 \over 3}(x+{1 \over 4})^{3 \over 2}|_0^4 =$

$={1 \over 3} ((3 + {1 \over 4}) - (0+{1 \over 4})) = {1 \over 3} ({13 \over 4} - {1 \over 4}) = {1 \over 3} * {12 \over 4} = 1$

Answer is:

$\int_L ydl = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** With $z(y)=y^2+iy$ then $dz=(2y+i)dy$ and ${\bf Im}\,\bar{z}=-y$ then with substitution find the integral. Answer should be $-\dfrac{16}{3}(1+2i)$.